# After install ubuntu 14.04 , windows 8 not showing in grub

Tags: boot, grub2

```
 Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 9Feb2015]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi 
                       /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT16
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 starts 
                       at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                       sdb2 starts at sector 1954316. According to the info 
                       in the boot sector, sdb2 has 0 sectors.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy
mount: /dev/sdb2 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb2 busy
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Windows installation to be found on your disk as shown in your post.

This is the reason why the GRUB boot menu doesn't have a  Windows menu entry.

Maybe you selected to use the whole disk for Ubuntu when you installed Ubuntu.

You may see a BIOS entry because /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi is still present on sda1.

When you want to have Windows back you unfortunately will have to reinstall it.

Comment: But i can see windows drive and also see windows boot loader in bios

Comment: @sibikilivayil: Then the BIOS entry is mistaken (referring to a no longer existing Windows installation) or you didn't attach the Windows drive while running Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

As cl-netbox suggested, you probably wiped windows. If you can see the windows entry in the boot menu try accessing it from there. If it doesn't boot, then it is a confirmation.